# Cqrs Complex commands for master detail tables

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I have a **CreateUserCommand** that responsible for creating accounts.

```
   public class UserCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<CreateUserCommand>
    {
        private readonly IUserRepository repository;

        public UserCommandHandler(IUserRepository repository)
        {
            this.repository = repository;
        }

        public void Handle(CreateUserCommand command)
        {
            User user = new User();
            user.Username = command.Username;
            user.Password = command.Password;
            user.Email = command.Email;

            repository.Add(user);
            repository.Save();
        }
    }
```

But I have UserInRoles Table including (UserId, RoleID) columns. So I have to add user in a role after creation.

How to do this nasted operations with CQRS?

Comment: So you both have a Users and a UserInRoles table and not just a missing RoleId value in the code above, correct?

Answer (score 0):

`UserCommandHandler` does seem to do a good job at creating a user object and storing it, but it doesn't reflect your use case well. Your use case for example results in "registering a user creates a new user object and assigns the new user role *X*".

Then I'd create a `RegisterUser` Domain Service (or put a method of this name into an appropriate existing service). Since "registering" new means more than "create user object", it's okay to do both in one sweep.

You could even re-use the `UserCommandHandler` if having it around on its own doesn't violate your business rules -- i.e. if it's forbidden to create users without giving them a role in all cases, don't provide a mechanism to just create user objects. Replace `UserCommandHandler` with the aforementioned `RegisterUser` instead.

I suggest you take a look at [Vernon's TenantProvisioningService](https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/blob/master/iddd_identityaccess/src/main/java/com/saasovation/identityaccess/domain/model/identity/TenantProvisioningService.java#L80) for inspiration.

There, `registerAdministratorFor` creates a user with all nested value objects, creates an admin role, and assigns the new user to that role.

Answer (score 0):

According to the tags, I guess, you are using domain model patterns. Then the User Aggregate should consist of User as an AggregateRoot and UserRoles as an Entity. You should pass the UserRoles information to create the whole Aggregate.

But if you are modeling the domain differently, you can always use domain events and domain services as a means to make changes on different aggregates in the same transaction. However, the issue of depending on database-generated identities may arise. In that case, I recommend using a client-generated identity like GUIDs or refactoring your modeling to reflect the dependence of entities more correctly (entities in an AggregateRoot are dependent on AggregateRoot creation).

Answer (score -1):

If a user MUST have a role and there is a default role then you can just insert the default role into the roles table as part of the `CreateUserCommand`

If a user must have a role but there is no default role, then include the role that the user must be in the `CreateUserCommand` and add the record to the table as part of the command. (you could also add the list of roles to add the user to the `CreateUserCommand` anyway and if it is empty just use a default role, otherwise use the explicitly defined roles)

If the user does not have to have a role then you can do either of the 2 options above, or you can add a new command `AddUserToRole(s)Command` and have the client issue these commands after the user has been created.

Your command handler can take a dependency on both repositories if your roles and users are in different repositories.